# How to override the text of JTableCell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple Java Desktop Application with swing JTable and DefaultTableModel.

So I have this code:

```
v = modelManager.getArticoliManager().estraiArticoli(false, true, false, false, false,null,false,null,null);
tableModelArticoli = new MyTableModelFatturaManuale(v, 
                datiFattura!= null ?datiFattura.getNumeroDecimali() : null);
sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModelFatturaManuale>(tableModelArticoli);

table = new JTable(tableModelArticoli);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
daiProprietaJTable();
//rimuovo la prima colonna, per avere più spazio
table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));

jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);
jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(dTabella);
```

So when I start my application, I can see the table like this:
[image]

In the third column for example, I have the quantity of goods, for example at the first row I have "0", now I want to insert 100, so I must before delete the "0" value then insert 100.
There is any way to override the text on the JTableCell?

Comment: I think you really want to go have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: Also, have a look at `TableModel::setValueAt`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922476/how-to-change-column-model-of-my-tablemodel-dynamically